# Nestjs: Reflector not injected to custom decorator

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I know there are other questions with the same name on the site but my context is pretty different so I'm going to ask.

I currently have a Turborepo like so:

```
apps/api
packages/pkg/PkgModule
packages/pkg/auth/AuthModule
packages/pkg/auth/PkgAuthStrategy
packages/pkg/auth/PkgAuthGuard
```

PkgModule imports and reexports PkgAuthModule and PkgAuthModule looks like so:

```js
@Module({ 
 imports: [ConfigModule, PkgAuthModule],
 providers: [PkgService],  
 exports: [PkgService, PkgAuthModule]
})
export class PkgModule {}
```

and PkgAuthModule looks like so

```js
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule.register({ session: false }), ConfigModule],
  providers: [PkgAuthStrategy, ConfigService],
  exports: [PkgAuthStrategy]
})
export class PkgAuthModule {}
```

My strategy just returns true for now. My guard extends `AuthGuard('pkg-auth')` . My problem is in my auth guard, when I use `this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>`,  reflector evaluates to undefined.

AuthGuard:

```js
@Injectable()
export class PkgAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('pkg-auth') {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    super()
  }

  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    console.log(this.reflector)
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>('public', [
       context.getHandler(),
       context.getClass(),
    ])

    if (isPublic) return true

    return super.canActivate(context)
  }
}
```

In api, I simply import PkgModule. The guard when used in an api controller does not inject Reflector properly.

Guard definition and usage are like so:

```js
export const Protected = () => UseGuards(PkgAuthGuard)
```

api.controller:

```
@Protected()
@Post('/<endpoint>')
public async endpoint(@Body() body: any) {
...
}
```

Little background: I have 2 auth strategies, Firebase and Pkg. PkgAuth is used to validate Webhook pushers. Firebase is used by the user and is working fine. They resemble each other in setup, only notable difference is PkgAuth is in a separate package in my monorepo.

Comment: and where have you registered `PkgAuthGuard`?

Comment: Hmm didn't have to register it with my other authentication. Looks like this:
`export const Protected = () => UseGuards(FirebaseAuthGuard)`

Comment: Can you show how you use the guard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution accidentally! I realized `ConfigModule` wasn't injected either so began investigating more vigorously. Turns out, because my module is in a separate Turborepo package that is then bundled and used by my Turborepo App, I needed to define all the Nestjs dependencies again:

`$ yarn add @nestjs/common @nestjs/core reflect-metadata rxjs`